# How to fix 'Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1(BASELINE)' flyway error?

Tags: java, flyway

I imported in a dataset with table creation for my app. However, when I try to start my server and during the time of ear deployment, I encounter an error with Flyway migration. The error is :

`Database migration failed.: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1 (BASELINE)`

I have checked that all database information is correct in dev.xml and have checked for errors in flyway_schema_history but none are present.

I have previously seen a communication link error but now that has disappeared. Could someone shed light on the issue because I don't feel like any of the scripts are running including the BASELINE?

Stack trace of error:

````java
2019-04-10 16:54:48,544 ERROR [com.cognitran.isis.model.migration.TopixFlywayIntegrator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) Database migration failed.: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected >failed migration to version 1 (BASELINE)```
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1375)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:82)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1257)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1249)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1604)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1249)
````

Answer (score 0):

> "Database migration failed.: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1 (BASELINE)"

it means that you ran migrate before and it failed at 1 for some reason. You need to identify why the previous migration failed at 1 and solve it if you have not already done so.
Once solved you need to run `flyway repair` to tell the flyway that whatever failed is out of the way.

Depending on how you set up and run `flyway` there are a few options to run repair:

- if this is maven based project, run `mvn flyway:repair` in the console. if using intelliJ you have this in maven plugins `maven -> <service name> -> plugins -> flyway -> flyway:repair`
- if this is some other project (i.e., flyway was installed with `brew`) then just run `flyway repair` in console

If it fails again, you are back on step 1.